# Unable to install pytorch on digital ocean droplet

Tags: pytorch, digital-ocean

I am trying to install pytorch on Digital Ocean droplet. I tried running

```
pip install torch
```

but it downloads the files and is automatically killed. I tried looking up this issue but it couldn't find any solution.

[image]